# MongoDB how to return multiple data in an array

Tags: mongodb, find

I have some data like

```
{"name":[{"age":15},{"age":18},{"age":20}]}
```

I want search age greater than 17, here is my script

```
db.test.find({"name.age":{"$gt":17}},{"name.age.$":1})
```

This will return

```
{"name":[{"age":18}]}
```

But I want get all data greater than 18

How to improve the script?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be to use the [**$redact**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator.

- Match all the records which have at least one sub document in the
  `name` array, which meet our search criteria.
- Keep only those sub documents in the `name` array, which are a match.

snippet:

```
var minimumAge = 17;
db.t.aggregate([
{$match:{"name.age":{$gt:minimumAge}}},
{$redact:{$cond:[
                 {$gt:[{$ifNull:["$age",minimumAge+1]},
                        minimumAge]},
                        "$$DESCEND",
                        "$$PRUNE"
                      ] 
            }

}
])
```